# Is it okay to do an npm install on another terminal window while nodemon is running?

Tags: node.js, npm

Let's say I am working on an app that listens on port 3000. Nodemon is running. I require another npm package in the app.js file, and on another terminal window that is open to the directory of that app, I run npm install (package name).

Will this cause any issues?

Comment: I would recommend that you take a look at the [Tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour) page before making a question. As it's mentioned there, we avoid chit-chat and require that you try solving the problem before making a question. Have you tried running that command while your app is running? What was the result?

Comment: I appreciate the advice. I followed the link you gave, and it was very helpful in teaching me how to ask proper questions. Now to answer your question, I did not see any issues on my end after running npm install while nodemon was running. I was wondering if it would lead to problems down the road, if it was something to avoid, etc. I guess it's fine, since I don't hear anybody warning me not to.

Answer (score 1):

I've just tested this case on `Node.js` project and turns out that installing additional library while `nodemon` was running from the secondary terminal doesn't cause any issues. After installation was complete, `nodemon` picked up changes and reloaded application.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. What I wanted to know was whether it was fine to do so or not, if it would cause issues later on with dependencies, etc. Thank you!